# SMS internal comment clouds

Tags: gratis, sms

I am looking for an app for sending and receiving SMS messages which will all live also letting you create and hierarchical trees of commentmesages. The nodes of the tree can be selected at a later time and sent according to diamond-shaped-message -: sending :- criteria-. (also defined by the, user,; and sent at will alter on in time. The first diamond is above the root node and it has only a send or don't-send action associated with it. All other nodes have send or don't send actions as well as a question with a yes no action to follow down the tree.

This would be for /advanced "" users.

Novice users can store special green (send" sms messages will be blue and received ones golden brown) messages can be sent along the conversation timeline as comments, which can be sent at a, later time.

The rest of the interface,) looks the same as on standard phones.

[image: SMS conversation with client-comment clouds (sendable at a later time)]

**Note**: The app must be free, the functionality is more important than the colors, was thinking about an Android app but ios is fine too. Through the menu one could also enable/disable the functionality I describe, making it available only to advanced users.

Comment: I read this through four times and still don'tr understand it (maybe a sketch would help). You are being extremely specific here, with talk of diamonds an colo(u)rs. Have you already seen such an app, or is this just your idea of it. **MUST** those green/blue/golden brown be exactly those colo(u)rs, or is it the functionality that is important? Is this for Android or iOS? Must it be free, or do you have a budget?  The more information that you give us, the more that we can help you. Please read [ask]